# C++11 code/library in non C++11 program

Tags: c++, c++11, compatibility

Assume that I compile the code in C++11 (I'll use Lambdas) to ".o" or library ".a".
And I have a program, where I will include previous library and header file, that I can't compile with C++11, but old one ( C++98 ).
Will it compile and work fine?

Comment: Well, does the header use any C++11 stuff?

Comment: some good info here: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Cxx11AbiCompatibility

Comment: @Cameron Header don't have a code implementations so not

Comment: It really depends on the Standard Library you are using too. Some Standard Library may implement the classes sufficiently differently in C++11 that it breaks compatibility with C++03. I would suggest you just bite the bullet and make everything compile with the same version of the Standard rather than live with the fear that it might break at any moment; undefined behavior can be completely non-trivial and nigh impossible to investigate.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not. The reason that name mangling (why the ABI changes) in c++ exists is because incompatibility differences between c++ versions can make code unstable if it will work at all.

If you have code that doesn't compile against c++11, you'll probably have to refactor one of your programs to compile against the other compiler. (Most likely get your old code to compile with the new compiler)

If this isn't an option, you can try and make the c++11 lib a DLL with a C interface or with a COM object interface, but exceptions would stop at that boundary, and if you go the DLL route, you would more than likely want to write a wrapper class to access the c++11 object, so that it acts like an object on your pre c++11 side of the boundary.

Answer (score 3):

It will work fine if:

1. the (public) header doesn't use any C++11 features
2. the ABI hasn't changed

   - consult your platform/compiler on this one
3. no common dependency has changed

   - as per the GCC document linked by Vaughn Cato, *this includes the standard library*. Anything that generates different code or object layouts when compiled with C++11, and is used by both library and client may be a problem ... even if it isn't used in the interface itself.

If point 3 is your only issue, you *may* be able to get around it by compiling a dynamic library (depending on platform a .so, or a .dynlib, or a DLL as Adrian suggests) with all dependencies statically linked internally and not exported. It's a bit hairy though.

Comment: I think that there are also some edge cases, such as the use and the behaviour of smart pointers, I remember a post here on SO explaining a possible issue with smart pointers that are seen as "regular" pointers in other versions of the language.

Comment: This is the best answer here actually, and it saved me writing my own. I would add that a C++11 library linked into a C++03 runtime using application can break many C++11 features e.g. std::current_exception() cannot be guaranteed to work correctly. Linking a C++11 library into a C++11 aware runtime which is linked into a C++03 compiled application works as intended though. In other words, use a modern C++ compiler and STL (keeping versions identical across all compilands), and you're very likely to be successful. Niall

Answer (score 2):

One common approach is to provide a C version of the API (`extern "C"` functions) with objects passed around using opaque pointers. This is more likely to be compatible between languages and compilers.